# what is the name of this component?

Tags: power-supply, identification

[image]

what is the name of this component? it's from a power supply.

Comment: ferrite bead it looks like

Comment: wow ferrite beads are the most questioned components here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those look like Ferrite Beads, or also called ferrite chokes.  They are usually there to suppress high frequency electric noises in a circuit.  Hope this helps!
[image]